# Recovering hex data from a large log-file using Ruby and RegEx

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to filter/append lines of hex data from a large log-file, using Ruby and RegEx.

The lines of the log-file that I need look like this:

```
Data: 10 55 61 (+ lots more hex data)
```

I want to add all of the hex data, for further processing later. The regex /^\sData:(.+)/ should do the trick.

My Ruby-program looks like this:

```
puts "Start"

fileIn = File.read("inputfile.txt")

fileOut = File.new("outputfile.txt", "w+")
fileOut.puts "Start of regex data\n"    

fileIn.each_line do
    dataLine = fileIn.match(/^\sData:(.+)/).captures    
    fileOut.write dataLine
end

fileOut.puts "\nEOF"
fileOut.close

puts "End"
```

It works - sort of - but the lines in the output file are all the same, just repeating the result of the first regex match.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over the same entire file. You need to iterate over the line.

```
fileIn.each_line do |line|
    dataLine = line.match(/^\sData:(.+)/).captures    
    fileOut.write dataLine
end
```

Comment: Good point! But now I get an error:
<code>
 Start
 sma_data.rb:20:in `block in <main>': undefined method `captures' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  from sma_data.rb:19:in `each_line'
  from sma_data.rb:19:in `<main>'
</code>

Comment: That means you have a line that does not match that regex. You need to apply `captures` only then `dataLine` is not nil.

Comment: I thought this might do:

    fileIn.each_line do |line|
     line =~ /^\sData:(.+)/
     if($1)
      fileOut.write $1
     end
    end

but I get this error:

     sma_regex.rb:12:in `block in <main>': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
      from sma_regex.rb:8:in `each_line'
      from sma_regex.rb:8:in `<main>'

PS: Can't seem to get code formatting to work